# split a string (ng-model) created inside ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs, split

I start to play with `angularjs`, and having this data model :

```
friends = [
    {name:'John**amine**allo'},
    {name:'Mary**aaa**mmm'},
    {name:'Mike**bb**kkk'}
]
```

I would like to split each name by '**' to create a table of names.

I don't know if there is more straightforward way to do this ( maybe using some filter in angular-filter module) but here what I have so far tried:

```
 <table id="searchObjResults">
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in friends">
      <td ng-repeat="y in x.split('**')">
        {{y}}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split `name` property if the `x` elements:

```
<td ng-repeat="y in x.name.split('**')">{{y}}</td>
```

However this is probably not very good idea what you are trying to do. First of all, you need to take care of proper table structure (correct header `colspan` values). Secondary, it's better to render already processed data structure, rather then converting values inside templates. It just makes it overcomplicated, not to mention makes watch expression slower.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5PXTW1gjpKwg7e3S6hRM?p=preview

Comment: thanks , I know that it is better to pre-process data before sending it to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom filter to specify the separator:

```
<table id="searchObjResults">
<tr><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in friends">
  <td ng-repeat="y in x.name | mysplit:'**'">
    {{y}}
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('mysplit', function() {
  return function(data, sep) {
    return data.split(sep);
  }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OR5TG8yF86zLszIy4lTf?p=preview)

Comment: i did something similar ,amazing that this filter does not exist in [angluar-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) project.